# Picturebox not Centering on Form Resize

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image-processing, designer

I am working on a C# windows form and I am having trouble re-centering the Picturebox image.

What I am looking to do is look at the resolution of the monitor and set the form to a full screen and then set the picturebox as a full screen within the form.

Windowstate is set to Maximized in designer, FormBorderstyle is set to None in Designer.

```
    void Monitorresolution()
    {
        // grabs the resolution of the monitor
        Screen screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
        screenWidth = screen.Bounds.Width;
        screenHeight = screen.Bounds.Height;
        //MessageBox.Show("height = " + screenWidth + "/n" + "Width = " + screenHeight);
        // grabs the resolution of the monitor

        // sets the size of the window of Pictureviewer
        this.ClientSize = new Size(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        // sets the size of the window of Pictureviewer

        // sets the size of the picturebox
        pictureBox1.Size = new Size(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        // sets the size of the picturebox

        // sets the size of the image inside picturebox
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        // sets the size of the image inside picturebox

        // center the image
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point((pictureBox1.Parent.ClientSize.Width / 2) - (pictureBox1.Width / 2), (pictureBox1.Parent.ClientSize.Height / 2) - (pictureBox1.Height / 2));
        // center the image


        // anchors the picturebox
        pictureBox1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;

        // MessageBox.Show("WTF");

        pictureBox1.Refresh();       
    }
```

The image will be off center, unless I remove the comment any of the messagebox statements.
With the messagebox on, the image is centered perfectly.

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it.

Thanks
Andy

---

### UpDate

I am showing more of the code to get a better picture of what I am doing and why pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
will not work for me in this case.

I have reordered the code a bit and placed the resize code in the form_load code.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Image_Viewer
{
public partial class imageViewer : Form
{
    System.Drawing.Point mouseDown;

    int newWidth = 0;
    int newHeight = 0;
    int newX = 0;
    int newY = 0;

    int screenWidth;
    int screenHeight;


    public imageViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var frm2 = new exitform();
        frm2.FormClosed += (o, e) => this.Close();
        frm2.Show();
    }

    private void imageViewer_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void imageViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            dlg.Title = "Open Image";
            dlg.Filter = "JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg|PNG|*.png|TIFF|*.tif;*.tiff|BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif|" + "All Graphics Types|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.tif;*.tiff";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                using (var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(dlg.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
                {
                    var bmp = new Bitmap(fs);
                    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
                    Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }

        // grabs the resolution of the monitor
        Screen screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
        screenWidth = screen.Bounds.Width;
        screenHeight = screen.Bounds.Height;
        // MessageBox.Show("height = " + screenHeight + "\n" + "Width = " + screenWidth);
        // grabs the resolution of the monitor


        // sets the size of the window of Pictureviewer
        this.ClientSize = new Size(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        // sets the size of the window of Pictureviewer

        pictureBox1.Size = new Size(screenWidth, screenHeight);

        pictureBox1.Location = new Point((ClientSize.Width / 2) - (pictureBox1.Width / 2), (ClientSize.Height / 2) - (pictureBox1.Height / 2));

        // MessageBox.Show("When this message box pops, everything seems to work, no idea why though");
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs mouse = e as MouseEventArgs;

        if (mouse.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            mouseDown = mouse.Location;
            pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.None;
        }

        else if (mouse.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            // Do something else, not important in this example
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs mouse = e as MouseEventArgs;

        if (mouse.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            // Pan functions
            Point mousePosNow = mouse.Location;

            int deltaX = mousePosNow.X - mouseDown.X;
            int deltaY = mousePosNow.Y - mouseDown.Y;

            int newX = pictureBox1.Location.X + deltaX;
            int newY = pictureBox1.Location.Y + deltaY;

            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(newX, newY);
        }

        else if (mouse.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs mouse = e as MouseEventArgs;

        if (mouse.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Point mousePosNow = mouse.Location;

            int deltaX = mousePosNow.X - mouseDown.X;
            int deltaY = mousePosNow.Y - mouseDown.Y;

            int newX = pictureBox1.Location.X + deltaX;
            int newY = pictureBox1.Location.Y + deltaY;

            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(newX, newY);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)//zoom function
    {
        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            newWidth = pictureBox1.Size.Width + (pictureBox1.Size.Width / 10);
            newHeight = pictureBox1.Size.Height + (pictureBox1.Size.Height / 10);

            newX = pictureBox1.Location.X - ((pictureBox1.Size.Width / 10) / 2);
            newY = pictureBox1.Location.Y - ((pictureBox1.Size.Height / 10) / 2);
        }

        else if (e.Delta < 0)
        {
            newWidth = pictureBox1.Size.Width - (pictureBox1.Size.Width / 10);
            newHeight = pictureBox1.Size.Height - (pictureBox1.Size.Height / 10);
            newX = pictureBox1.Location.X + ((pictureBox1.Size.Width / 10) / 2);
            newY = pictureBox1.Location.Y + ((pictureBox1.Size.Height / 10) / 2);
        }

        pictureBox1.Size = new Size(newWidth, newHeight);
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(newX, newY);
    }

}
}
```

---

### Form 2 uses the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Image_Viewer
{
public partial class exitform : Form
{
    private const int CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON = 0x200;

    public exitform()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams myCp = base.CreateParams;
            myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle | CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON;
            return myCp;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
}
```

---

I am only showing form 2's code just to show an exit button.  I show it on top of form 1 and remove the close button from both.

AppDeveloper I did try the code you posted however it did not work in my case,  I will retry in a smaller form for testing purposes.  What I find strange though is it does for some reason work after the messagebox.

Thanks
Andy

Comment: when is `Monitorresolution()` method called? form load?

Comment: I have tried it from form_load and immediately after InitializeComponent().  It seems strange to me that the code seems to work correctly after a messagebox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what the problem was

I was missing the dock style.  If I insert it just under the

```
pictureBox1.Location = new Point((ClientSize.Width / 2) - (pictureBox1.Width / 2), (ClientSize.Height / 2) - (pictureBox1.Height / 2));

pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
```

It seems to work perfectly every time.

Thanks to everyone who looked at this for me.

Andy

Answer (score 2):

#### You should center the `pictureBox1` location with respect to the `Form` it is hosted on (i.e. Parent Control/Form).

I am not sure why you are centering the image with respect to the `PrimaryScreen`

A better way to center the pictureBox would be to Subscribe to the `Form.Resize` event and adjust the `pixtureBox1` location dynamically.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Resize += Form1_Resize;
}

private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Left = (this.Width - pictureBox1.Width)/2;
    pictureBox1.Top = (this.Height - pictureBox1.Height)/2;
}
```

Comment: The reason I was trying it this way was I wanted a full screen image viewer, so my thought was to force the form to the size of the primary display and then force the imagebox to the size of the form. After that I have another form pop with a exit button and allowed zoom in/out and pan.  I will post more of the code to show a better picture of what I am performing.

Answer (score 2):

As I see, you are setting the size of the picturebox = size of the form. In your case it's better to just set

```
pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

and forget about setting size/proper resizing :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this interferes with my zoom in/out and pan code that I haven't posted.  I should have shown that code as well.  I will re-post additional code.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer C++ CLI, but the next example should be clear.

```
    Void MyForm::SetFullScreen(Boolean value)
    {
        if (value == FullScreen)
            return;

        if (value)
        {
            // DO NOT REORDER!!!
            this->LastWindowState = WindowState;                
            this->WindowState = FormWindowState::Normal;
            this->LastWindowBounds = Bounds;
            this->FormBorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::None;                              
            this->Bounds = Screen::PrimaryScreen->Bounds;
        }
        else
        {
            // DO NOT REORDER!!!
            this->WindowState = LastWindowState;
            this->FormBorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::Sizable;
            this->Bounds = LastWindowBounds;                    
        }

         Int32 NewX = (pictureBox1.Parent.ClientSize.Width / 2) - (pictureBox1.Width / 2);
         Int32 NewY = (pictureBox1.Parent.ClientSize.Height / 2) - (pictureBox1.Height / 2);
         pictureBox1.Location = new Point(NewX, NewY);
         pictureBox1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None; 

        // finally save the actual state
        FullScreen = value;
    }
```